# How do I identify instances in Javadoc or pseudo code?

Tags: javadoc

I am tempted to write something as follows:

```
StringBuilder.append(String.format("%d %f", x, y));
```

But, I know that I am really working with an instance of StringBuilder and I do not mean to be invoking a static append method.  Is there a commonly practiced way of writing such Javadoc or pseudo code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to write `StringBuilder#append(...)` here to indicate that this is an instance method to be called on an instance of StringBuilder, not a class (static) method, contrasting to a class method like `String.valueOf(...)`.

I'm not sure there is a definite convention about this, though.

Comment: This question (and my answer) is about using different notations for static and nonstatic members, not about using `#` in Javadoc `@see` tags (where you use it for both static and nonstatic members). I clarified my answer to make this clear.